# How do I use the .toggle function?

Tags: javascript, toggle, jsfiddle

I am trying to use `.toggle` bellow but it doesn't seem to be working.

What I am aiming to happen is that when you click on the click text, a box comes from outside of view of the page and horizontally enters to a certain position. And when you click again it goes back to the  position off screen. Bellow I have just been messing about with the vertical height. But I can't seem to get the toggle function to work?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#click").toggle(Click1, Click2).click(function Click1() {
    $(".test").animate({
        top: "300px"
    });
});

$("#click").click(function Click2() {
    $(".test").animate({
        top: "30px"
    });
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxmitch/UgEu6/2/)

Comment: you can make it without toggle like this
        $(".test").hide();
        $("#click").show();
 
    $('#click').click(function(){
    $(".test").slideToggle();
    });

Comment: I would rather it to slide in. Any ideas?

Comment: what you mean with slide in? please explain i don't get it :)

Comment: Like animate from outside the page to a certain point?

Comment: Oh!, you can add a callback function to the slideToggle()

$(".test").slideToggle(function() {
    $(this).animate({top: "30px" });   
  }
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toggle` binds the `.click` event for you.  You *don't* call both `.toggle` and `.click`.

Because of how you are creating the `Click1` and `Click2` functions, they are *not* hoisted to the top of the scope.  The variables `Click1` and `Click2` are only defined *inside* themselves, not in their higher scope.

You should bind the event like this:

```
$("#click").toggle(function() {
    $(".test").animate({
        top: "300px"
    });
}, function() {
    $(".test").animate({
        top: "30px"
    });
});
```

Comment: Now for some reason the click button just disappears? http://jsfiddle.net/maxmitch/UgEu6/

Comment: @maxmitch: Huh?  What does that have to do with this question?

Comment: Have you looked at the jsfiddle?

Comment: @maxmitch: Yes, and I don't see `#click` anywhere in there.  Nor do I see the `.toggle` code.  Are you sure that's the right fiddle for this question?

Comment: @maxmitch: AH!  I see why that's happening.  [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) (the "event") was removed in jQuery 1.9.  It's calling the other [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method (for showing/hiding).